# CASE statement with LIKE during LISTAGG Operation

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, listagg

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| Person_ID | First_Name | Last_Name | Igroup_ID |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|         2 | Rick       | Hudson    |       100 |
|         2 | Rick       | Hudson    |        50 |
|         2 | Rick       | Hudson    |        28 |
|         2 | Rick       | Hudson    |        15 |
|         3 | John       | Hardy     |       150 |
|         3 | John       | Hardy     |       100 |
|         4 | Tom        | Johnson   |       200 |
|         4 | Tom        | Johnson   |       150 |
|         4 | Tom        | Johnson   |       100 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Please refer the above table the reason behind the usage of operation LISTAGG , I am getting Mutliple rows of Person ID since I have each person associated with multiple Group ID , So I wanted to Concatenate the Group ID using LISTAGG and seggregate the values.

And since there are so many values IGROUP Values a each person can associate , But we worried about first 2 values , In the screenshot

When something returns 100|50 Then 'GroupA'
When something returns 150|100 Then 'GroupB'
When something returns 200|150 Then 'GroupC'

```
(CASE LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID , '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) 
          WHEN  '100|50' THEN 'GroupA'
          WHEN  '150|100' THEN 'GroupB'
          WHEN  '200|150 THEN 'GroupC'
     END) AS SERVICES
```

But here the problem is if I use above way I have to define all the combinations in the CASE statement

Is there any way I can use `WHEN LIKE '100|50%'` THEN GroupA

Comment: I must say that something does not feel right with this question/approach. I strongly suggest that you'll add a new question for the whole query/issue

Comment: Still not clear.(1) Do you care only 50,100,150, and 200? What special about those values? What about other values? (2) What are you going to do with the results? (3) In your original question a group ID could appear more than once per person ID, how can it be in this data structure? (4) How come the data is not normalized in the first place? Why do you have the name here in addition to the person ID? I assume that if you'll give the whole picture the solution would be completely different. P.s. Please replace the picture with text (You can format it with ctrl+k)

Comment: 1) Not Like that , I just made it easy to undrestand.
2) Those values kind of Skills of the Person and I need to seggregate the person based on the skills, for example if he have 50and 100 he belongs to one group
3) Group ID is kind of Skills and person can have mutliple skills(But if he satisfies 2 skills i can identify the GroupA,GroupB,GroupC Skills)
4) I don't have hold on this option ,Sure I will work and replace picture with text

Comment: My Only Intension is i will get so many combination like below but when I do LISTAGG operation i get the values as below. So instead of writing WHEN statement each and every time. I wanted to use WHEN LIKE ( 50|100%) Then GroupA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a flag column for each value that interest you.
Once you have it you can easily do whatever analyze you need.

```
select    person_id

         ,max (case when igroup_id =  15 then 1 else 0 end) as is_15
         ,max (case when igroup_id =  28 then 1 else 0 end) as is_28
         ,max (case when igroup_id =  50 then 1 else 0 end) as is_50
         ,max (case when igroup_id = 100 then 1 else 0 end) as is_100
         ,max (case when igroup_id = 150 then 1 else 0 end) as is_150
         ,max (case when igroup_id = 200 then 1 else 0 end) as is_200

from      mytable

group by  person_id

order by  person_id
```

---

```
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| PERSON_ID | IS_15 | IS_28 | IS_50 | IS_100 | IS_150 | IS_200 |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|         2 |     1 |     1 |     1 |      1 |      0 |      0 |
|         3 |     0 |     0 |     0 |      1 |      1 |      0 |
|         4 |     0 |     0 |     0 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

Simply extract only the first 2 values and check them

```
(
    CASE    regexp_substr
            (
                LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID , '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id)
               ,'[^|]*\|[^|]*'
            )

        WHEN '50|100'  THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN '100|100' THEN 'No'
    END
) AS SERVICES
```

Comment: I will try this one

Comment: Thanks Dudu For me regexp_substr soln provided by you  is better , I have problem with Oracle ,Once instance is up I will try and and confirm !!.

Answer (score 3):

As for the CASE+LIKE, you need to use the so-called "searched syntax" of CASE:

```
CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <result>
    [WHEN <condition> THEN <result>
     ...]
    [ELSE <result>] 
END
```

If you want to keep the default ELSE NULL but don't want to repeat the LISTAGG, you need to wrap your query. E.g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN la LIKE '50|100%' THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN la LIKE '100|100%' THEN 'No
        END services
  FROM ( SELECT LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID , '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) la
          ....
       ) t
```

However, not that it is rather uncommon to test group conditions using LISTAGG. It is more common to use CASE inside of aggregates. E.g. to check if there is exaclty one group member with igroup_id = 50, use this condition

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN igroup_id = 50 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

To implement the same logic as your LISTAGG approach (exactly one 50, at least one 100, and no other value < 100), you can do this:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN igroup_id = 50 THEN 1 END) = 1
      AND COUNT(CASE WHEN igroup_id = 100 THEN 1 END) >= 1
      AND COUNT(CASE WHEN igroup_id < 100 THEN 1 END) = 1 -- one for 50
     THEN 'Yes',

    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN igroup_id = 100 THEN 1 END) >= 2
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN igroup_id < 100 THEN 1 END) = 0
    THEN 'No'
END
```

This might look overly complex, but chances are that the complexity is just because I re-implemented your LISTAGG approach. Knowing the side conditions (e.g., if igroup_id happens to be unique) might make this approach less bulky.

Here are some articles I wrote about...

... CASE : http://modern-sql.com/feature/case

... the trick to use CASE in Aggregates: http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

... LISTAGG: http://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg (but I think the use of listagg is bad for your purpose).

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question can you please help me with the better approach.

Comment: @Batman:you will need to ask a new question for any new info,its not good approach to modify question and ask again

Comment: @Gemeiswar I will make sure this. Here I just updated the same question with additional Info

Answer (score 1):

You can take that listagg value in subquery and join the same with main table then write case statement as per ur requirement.

```
Select t.*, case when list_value like '100|50%' THEN 'GroupA'
          WHEN list_value like '150|100%' THEN 'GroupB'
          WHEN  list_value like '200|150%' THEN 'GroupC' end as services
From 
(Select distinct Person_ID,First_Name,Last_Name from urtable) t
Join
(Select Person_ID,
LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID , '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id desc) list_value from urtable group by Person_ID) g on (t.Person_ID=g.Person_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding i guess you require one record per `Person_Id` along with the result which as per your provided cases i.e. `Group_A/Group_B/Group_C`

```
WITH Test_Result AS 
(SELECT person_id,first_name,last_name,listagg(igroup_id,'|') within GROUP 
(ORDER BY rownum) list_agg_res FROM sof_3 GROUP BY 
person_id,first_name,last_name)

SELECT person_id,first_name,last_name,list_agg_res,
CASE WHEN list_agg_res LIKE '100|50%' THEN 'Group_A' 
WHEN  list_agg_res LIKE '150|100%' THEN 'Group_B' 
WHEN list_agg_res LIKE '200|150%' THEN 'Group_C' 
ELSE NULL END Final_Res FROM Test_Result;
```

Hope the above query will help !!